# How to store multiple emails to a database in one form submission?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm building a system that allows an organisations members to refer newsletters they receive to their friends or family. What I thought about doing was to give these members a page that would allow them to add that persons name and email address in to a form. This form would be limited to 5 email names and email addresses, so you would essentially have five rows with two HTML form inputs per row.

My problem is that I don't know how I would reliably add this to a database? Would I need 5 individual forms that would then be submitted by one Form submit button?

**EDIT**
What I have at the moment is two tables. A `member` table and a `referral` table. When the member starts to the referral process their data is added to the `member` table, and then their ID is taken.

The `member` table consists of the following fields:

```
ID
Firstname
Surname
Email
Referrer
```

When the member add's their own details, I then take their ID and store it for use later.

Then, I want to have a form that looks like this:

```
Referral 1:  their email address   -  their name
Referral 2:  their email address   -  their name
Referral 3:  their email address   -  their name
Referral 4:  their email address   -  their name
Referral 5:  their email address   -  their name
```

This is so that I can add their information to the `referral` table, which would look like this will all the data added:

```
ID   |   Firstname   |   Surname   |   Email            |   Referrer
==========================================================================
1    |   Joe         |   Bloggs    | joe@bloggs.com     |    1
2    |   John        |   Bloggs    | john@bloggs.com    |    1
3    |   James       |   Bloggs    | james@bloggs.com   |    1
4    |   Jordan      |   Bloggs    | jordan@bloggs.com  |    1
5    |   Jack        |   Bloggs    | jack@bloggs.com    |    1
```

This is what the end product should be.

Comment: Who are these email addressed liked to? is it someone signing up so when they provide their details they can add the new email addresses right?

Comment: It can be done with one form. From what I understand, you're trying to do something fairly standard, so just try and see if something breaks, and post it here.

Comment: Yeah best bet is to write out what you want to do step by step in English. For me it usually becomes more clear once writing on paper. Also an answer that might be of some help.

Comment: Still not 100% sure what your asking. Are you asking for use to do the work for you?

Comment: No, I'm trying to work out how to get that form in to the database, so it creates a record per row filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need one form and then the user id of the person who is logged in.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl (name, email, referrer) VALUES ('" . $_POST[name . $i] . "', '" . $_POST[email . $i] . "', '" . $_SESSION[user_id] . "')");
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
            <?php
                for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
                {
                    echo '<p>';
                    echo 'Name ' . $i;
                    echo '<input type="text" name="name' . $i . '" id="name' . $i . '">';
                    echo 'Email ' . $i;
                    echo '<input type="text" name="email' . $i . '" id="email' . $i . '">';
                    echo '</p>';
                }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="save">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could have the extra email addresses in the signup for all with different names, for example, guest_email_1, guest_email_2 and so on.

Then on the database side you could either add some new fields to that users  record to add these email addresses to or you could make a new table that is for storing these guest emails. In this table you could have the ID of the person that signed them up so you have a reference of where that email address came from if you should need it.

Is that what you're looking for?

**Edit** I think you might be looking for a way to get the ID of the user that was just added. So lets say a user summits the form and they're added to the database table but now we have to add their ID as well as the email addresses to the other table. If this is right and you are using mysqli then there is a function `mysqli_insert_id` Here is the manual for it:

```
[mysqli_inser_id - manual][1]
```

This function will get the last ID added to the database then you can use it to store the other email addresses with the ID of the original users.

That it?

Comment: I have a table that will associate the members ID to the referred person's details. So yeah thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think i know what you're looking for, i will update my answer now.

Comment: @mickburkejnr I have added to my original answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I realised the question is a bit too vauge, I've edited the question to say what I'm stuck with